# what's the HTML entity code for "«"

Tags: html, web-development

What's the HTML entity code for the character that *looks like* "`«`" (but it's not the less-than sign)

Comment: Why am I being down voted?

Comment: That character isn't in ASCII.

Comment: You're being voted down because this isn't a programming question, and the answer is easily found by googling.

Comment: Wouldn't this belong in doctype or webmasters?

Answer (score 8):

This is know as left double angle quotes. You can implement them as `&#171` or `&laquo;`. I use this [site](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for all my <strike>ASCII</strike>HTML code needs.

Answer (score 3):

`&#8810;` gives you "≪"  (MUCH LESS-THAN)

`&#171;` gives you "«" (LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is this: 
    «

It is

```
&laquo;
```

Answer (score 1):

`&#171;` (from [this link](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html)).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

```
&#171;
```

[Link](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The character you want is called "LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK" in Unicode. It is at code point U+00AB. It can be found in the [C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) code chart.